# Why plt.figure(figsize=(w,h)) has no effect on df.barh() but plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [w,h] does?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I don't seem to be able to find answer in Matplotlib or anywhere on line why

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,20))
df.plot.barh()
```

does not change the plot size. I have to use this instead

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [15, 20]
df.plot.barh()
```

Can someone explain what is the difference between `plt.figure` and `plt.rcParams` please ?

How do I reset the effect of `plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [w,h]` to the original size in jupyter notebook after using it ? I tried `plt.rcdefaults()` but the default figure size still much bigger ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `barh` will create a new figure and axes if one is not explicitly passed to it. Therefore, when you do `plt.figure(figsize=(15,20))` you are creating a figure but never using it.

Whereas `plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [15, 20]` affects all figures.

One solution would be to create the figure and axes and pass it in as an argument

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,20))
df.plot.barh(ax=ax)
```

Alternatively, `barh` has a `figsize` argument that can be used. Therefore don't create a figure beforehand, simply do

```
df.plot.barh(figsize=(15,20))
```

Comment: You are correct([source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/plotting/_core.py)). You see that `ax` defaults to `None` in the pandas plotting module. If it detects None during setup it will create a figure.

Comment: `plt.rcdefaults()` works for me (as long as you are not setting the figure size of the current figure somewhere else)

Comment: Thanks @DavidG. How do I restore `df.plot.barh(figsize=(15,20))` back to its default size then ?

Comment: Do you mean once the figure has been created, how to change the size?